# jQuery Toggle old and new html value

Tags: html, jquery

How to toggle between the old and new html value in jQuery?

html

```
<span id="Password">&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;</span> 
<i class="fa-regular fa-eye passw"></i>
```

jQuery

```
$(".passw").click(function(){
  var passw = "12345678";
  //$("#Password").toggle.html(passw);
  $("#Password").html.toggle(passw);
});
```

Comment: `.toggle()` is for toggling classes, not contents. There's no function for toggling HTML, just use `if/else`.

Comment: @barmar can you post it as answer?

Comment: @Barmar actually .toggle() *"toggles"*. .toggleClass() is for classes. Anyway, html does not have a toggle method, it's a function .html() that returns the innerHTML

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan oh, duh! `.toggle()` is for toggling visibility, not contents.

Comment: If in doubt, review the docs, they're quite extensive [.toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) *Display or hide the matched elements* - elements, not html/text/content.

Comment: Given the `$("..").html.` construct, I'll also recommend [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/).

Comment: I'll also suggest using `$("..").text(pwd)` to set the password rather than `.html(..)` as who knows what nefarious content the password may contain (especially if user supplied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if/then` statement. When you toggle the content, you can save the old contents with `.data()`.

```js
$(".passw").click(function() {
  var passw = "12345678";
  $("#Password").html(function(i, oldhtml) {
    if (oldhtml == passw) {
      return $(this).data("saved-pass");
    } else {
      $(this).data("saved-pass", oldhtml);
      return passw;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Password: <span id="Password">&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;</span>
<i class="fa-regular fa-eye passw">Toggle</i>
```

Note that most sites use an `<input type="password">` for entering passwords, not a span. To reveal and hide the password they toggle the type between `password` and `text`.

Comment: As an additional caveat: if you don't have control over the password, be sure to use `.text(function ...` rather than `.html(function ...`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative (and easier to implement) solution is to include both visible and obscured password in the HTML initially, eg:

```js
$("#password-toggle").on("click", () => {
    $("#Password,#Password-Obscured").toggle();
});
```

```html
<span id="Password" style='display:none'>P4$$w0rd</span> 
<span id="Password-Obscured">&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;</span> 
<br/><button type='button' id="password-toggle">toggle password</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, this may not fit your scenario if the password is only a variable - in that case I'd do

```
$("#Password").text(pwd)
```

just before the .toggle, or in doc.ready, or after it's set if loading via ajax etc.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you really want to use [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```js
$('#Password').click(function(){
  $(this).toggle();
});
```

```css
#Password {
  font-size: 16px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Password[style="display: none;"] {
  display: inline!important;
  font-size: 0;
}

#Password[style="display: none;"]:before {
  content: attr(data-password);
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
Test <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="Password" data-password="0123456789">&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;&#x2022;</span> test
```